# Unable to download files from firebase storage on linux server using curl gives segmentation-fault

Tags: linux, bash, curl, linux-kernel, segmentation-fault

**Problem :**

This is quite weird that Firebase storage does not allow access to files on Linux server

When I run command `curl <download url>`, it responds with this :

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "Permission denied. Could not perform this operation"
  }
}
```

my Firebase storage rules are alright

**What i have tried ?**

also, as when i open the download URL in browser, it automatically starts file download

just to make sure that my server code is alright
I ran a test using [file.io](https://file.io) file was downloaded without a problem

Please comment if you know anything about this behavior of Firebase storage.

---

**Requested data**

this is the url i m trying => https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/famenun-2943.appspot.com/o/App%2Ftest.zip?alt=media&token=7b9ad4bf-de7b-4bd5-aaf2-58e54923a1d7

**New Problem**

After applying Robsiemb's suggestion this 403 is gone 
but the purpose is still not met !!!

One more thing I forgot to mention is that I m executing the command through sh file and which is being executed through a php file and i observed one more thing is that it gives an error called "segmentation fault"

I googled it but couldn't find anything wrong in my code

When i execute the sh file through terminal  it works fine but as when i execute it through php file it fails

i must have told all this in the first go
i was expecting it to be a normal problem
but this is quite deep

thanks for the comments and suggestions :)
please help

Comment: ```my firebase storage rules are alright``` - i'm not convinced, post your rules

Comment: When you access a file using the download URL you're bypassing the security rules, so that can't be the cause.

Comment: @HarKal: please edit your question to include an actual URL that is not working for you.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen sir please help. the file is only downloading when i manually give the command but when the machine executes the instructions using bash file it doesnt download the file gives the same error and saves it to the file i want it to download like 'sudo curl -o <filename> <url_in_quote>' so it saves the above 403 error response to the file. as when i try 'more filename' it shows me that what could be the reason behind this ?

Comment: The file link seems fine, so the problem is likely in your code. Without seeing the [minimal, complete/standalone code that any one of us can run to reproduce the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) it'll be hard to say more. I'd highly recommend reading the link though, as it contains many great hints on how to ensure we can actually help you solve the problem you're encountering.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen ok sir. ask me what you want to see i ll show you _/\_

Answer (score 2):

You likely need to quote the URL you are passing to curl, as it has shell special characters in it (notably '?' and '&').

e.g.

```
curl 'https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/[path]?alt=media&token=[gibberish]'
```

Without the quotes, the shell is likely to drop everything after the &, which includes the auth token, thus you get a permission denied.

Comment: As per Frank's comment above, then, please include the actual url and command you are using in the question.

Comment: sry bro that thing worked but still not behaving as expected. by putting quotes around the url this error is gone. see the edit and please comment if you know something

Answer (score 2):

When you create a Firebase project, a GCP project will be created and linked to the Firebase one. 
This means that whenever you create a bucket on Firebase, you will have the same bucket and all your data on the GCP project.

Knowing this, I reproduced you issue, and I got the same error 403 (I noticed that it was because authentication rules in Firebase), then I changed the rules and it worked.

In your case, you should set the specific headers to your request, by following the documentation from [Cloud Storage Authentication](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/authentication#apiauth):

```
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer ACCESS_TOKEN" "https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/example-bucket/o"
```

Comment: let me try it. give me some time. i ll get back to you, btw thanks

Answer (score 1):

I have replicated your issue and could download the file with no problem. This is my code:

```
<?php
$output = shell_exec("curl '<your_file_url>' -o <destination_file>");
```

My configurations are:
Php version: 7.3
Firebase storage rules: read and write

Can you confirm this is your settings also?

Comment: Hey @HarKal, can you then provide me with Php version and the exact error message.

Comment: i m using php 7 and the error doesn't occur in php code. everything works smoothly. i think the error is in tha bash file and it gives "segmentation fault"